# Scala import statement at top and inside scala class

Tags: scala

In scala what is the difference between these two import strategies

**Option 1**

```
import com.somepackage

class MyClass {
  //further code
}
```

**Option 2**

```
class MyClass {
  import com.somepackage
  //further code
}
```

Comment: The scope of `com.sompackage` is different!

Answer (score 22):

In Scala, `import`s are lexically scoped. `import`ed identifiers are only visible within the scope they were `import`ed in.

In the first case, the scope is the file, so, `import`s will be visible in the entire file, but not in other files. In the second case, the scope is the class, so `import`s will be visible in the entire class, but not in other classes *even* in the same file (except of course classes nested within `MyClass`).

You can also limit the scope of an `import` just to a single method an even a single block(!)

```
class Foo {
  def bar {
    // do something
    {
      import baz.quux.Frotz
      // use Frotz
    }
    // Frotz not visible here
  }
}
```

This is a nice example of Scala's regularity, orthogonality and simplicity. E.g. in Java, blocks create scopes for local variables but not for `import`s (or methods or anything else). In Scala, blocks create scopes. Period. No exceptions, no corner cases.

The `import` sits in between the curly braces, ergo it is only visible between the curly braces. It just does what you expect.

Answer (score 10):

The difference is:

In `Option 1` the import is viable for the complete scope. i.e any class/trait/function in `com.somePackage` can be used anywhere inside/outside the `MyClass`

But in case of `Option 2` it can only be used inside the `MyClass` and not outside it because scope of `import` is limited to inside `MyClass` only.